# Changing value in one DF based on value in another DF with mismatched rows

Tags: r, functional-programming

Below, I describe what I am trying to do as best I can, and then include my best attempt MWE (includes 2 csv files).

**The problem:** I have two DFs. One, call it `mweLookUps` has columns `pLU`, `vMax` and say 10 rows. Another, call it `mweData` has columns `p`, `v` and `vPrime,` with say 100 rows.

I want to alter the value in every row of `mweData` such that if the value of `v` is higher than `vMax` in `mweLookUps` where `pLU` is the same as the value of `p` in `mweData` for the given row, it is replaced with the value of `vMax.`

**SOLUTION MWE**

```
mweData <- data.frame(p = c(rep(c(34:36), 5), rep(50:53, 5)), v = runif(35, 1000, 20000))
mweData$vPrime <- mweData$v
mweLookUps <- data.frame(p = c(34:36, 50:53), vMax = runif(7, 1600, 12000))
foo <- merge(mweData, mweLookUps, by = 'p')
foo$vPrime <- ifelse(foo$v > foo$vMax, foo$vMax, foo$v)
```

**My attempt**

```
mweData <- data.frame(p = c(rep(c(34:36), 5), rep(50:53, 5)), v = runif(35, 1000, 20000))
mweData$vPrime <- mweData$v
mweLookUps <- data.frame(p = c(34:36, 50:53), vMax = runif(7, 1600, 12000))
logic <- mweLookUps$p == mweData$p
tmp <- mweLookUps[logic, "vMax"]
mweData[mweData$vPrime > tmp, "vPrime"] <- tmp
```

> Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, mweData$vPrime > tmp, "vPrime", value = c(3323.34631364793,  : 
>     missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I tried to further improve the ease of running the thing by replacing the csv files with the commands I used to generate them. I also tried to update the naming conventions in the code to match what I have in my description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand right what you need, but if I do, here is how I'd do it.

```
# merge on column p
foo <- merge(mweData, mweLookUps, by = "p") 
#for each row, if v > vMax, put vMax into vPrime, else put v into vPrime
foo$vPrime <- ifelse(foo$v > foo$vMax, foo$vMax, foo$v)
```

Comment: this is pretty much exactly it, thanks a bunch :D I will clean up the couple of issues and add it to my question. the main think is that for merge it has to be by = "p" rather than by = p ... the other thing is just that i want the result of the ifelse to be in foo$vPrime instead of foo$v

Comment: Indeed, sorry for the typo. Edited the answer to what you need.

Answer (score 3):

This could be also done with `pmin` after `merge`ing.  Using the `dplyr` join,

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(mweData, mweLookUps, by = "p") %>% 
                       mutate(v = pmin(vMax, v))
```